# Finding all possible bin combinations

Tags: python, combinations, slice, binning

I have 100.000 observations with a variable `age` on the range of 18-80. I want to find `X` bins based on the `age` variable. The bin ranges must not overlap and should combined span the entire interval. For instance, with `X = 4` one possible bin combination could be:

- 18-30
- 31-45
- 46-57
- 58-80

How can I find all possible bin combinations given a value `X`?

**Edit:** Prompted by @Wolf, here is another constraint that I was thinking of implementing myself. Each bin must hold at least 10 values for the `age` variable. That of course limits `X` so `X <= 6`.

I've tried to integrate this into the answer by @mkrieger1, but failed.

```
def bin_combinations(values, n):
    """
    Generate all possible combinations of splitting the values into n
    contiguous parts.

    >>> list(bin_combinations('abcd', 3))
    [['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd']]
    """

    for indices in combinations(range(1, len(values)), n - 1):
        li = list(indices)
        starts = [None] + li
        ends = li + [None]
        size = li[-1] - li[0]
        if size >= 10:
            yield [values[start:end] for start, end in zip(starts, ends)]
```

Comment: Are there any further restrictions to that bins? For example, would `18, 19, 20, 21-80` be a valid combination?

Comment: Have you tried to adapt my solution to your constrained problem?

Comment: Yes, but I'm having difficulty throwing an entire set of bins away instead of just a single bin. See code below:  `for indices in combinations(range(1, len(values)), n - 1):
        li = list(indices)
        starts = [None] + li
        ends = li + [None]
        size = li[-1] - li[0]
        if size >= 10:
            yield [values[start:end] for start, end in zip(starts, ends)]`

Comment: I've tried a couple of different alterations, but no luck.

Comment: What about integrating into the question what you've already tried? This will be more readable than within the comment and is absolutely SO-conform ;-)

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I've integrated it into the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Most appropriately, you find combinations by using the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from the `itertools` standard library module.

```
from itertools import combinations

def bin_combinations(values, n):
    """
    Generate all possible combinations of splitting the values into n
    contiguous parts.

    >>> list(bin_combinations('abcd', 3))
    [['a', 'b', 'cd'], ['a', 'bc', 'd'], ['ab', 'c', 'd']]
    """
    for indices in combinations(range(1, len(values)), n - 1):
        starts = [None] + list(indices)
        ends = list(indices) + [None]
        yield [values[start:end] for start, end in zip(starts, ends)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've added another constraint (see my post).